# Find out how many days till next birthday and previous birthday - javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

#### I am trying to find out how many days until there next birthday aswell as when there last one was. So far I have tried just seeing if todays day is the same as the one they inputted

Basically I have a form that the user gives there Date of birth, I then want to find out how many days until there next birthday will be, as well as when there last birthday was. I can't find anything on the internet. here is what i've tried so far.

```
var userInput = new Date(document.getElementById('selDay').value, document.getElementById('selMonth').value);
    var today = new Date(bdate.getDay(),bdate.getMonth());

    if(userInput == today)
    {
        alert('Birthday Today');
    }

    var untilBirthday = '';
    var sinceBirthday = '';
```

#### I cannot get it too even show if the userInput is the same as todays day

Comment: What’s `bdate`? I don’t see it defined anywhere.

Comment: To use the duplicate question to do previous birthday, swap firstdate for seconddate